# RxSwift: delay observable until another observable is finished?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I load posts from the server and want to show them **only** when their images are **all loaded**.
Here's what I was trying to do:

```
postsRepository
    .fetchPosts()
    .flatMap { posts -> Observable<[Post]> in
        return Observable.merge(posts.map({ /* Code that returns Observable<UIImage> */ }))
            .takeLast(1)
            .map { _ in posts }
    }
```

However, this code above loads images twice: once all the posts are fetched and once I bind posts to the table view. How to deal with that?

Comment: Can you try to explain your reasoning in what you do in your existing code? I understand you want to map posts to their images, by why do you take the last image, and then map it back into a post?

Comment: This is an ugly way to wait for the images to be loaded

Comment: Well I get that much, but how does it work?

Comment: How do you bind to the table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun one...

```
let postsWithImages = postsRepository
    .fetchPosts()
    .flatMap { posts in
        Observable.combineLatest(
            posts
                .map { $0.imageURL }
                .map { URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: URLRequest(url: $0))
                    .map { UIImage(data: $0) }
                    .catchErrorJustReturn(nil)
                }
            )
            .map { zip(posts, $0) }
    }
    .map { $0.map { (post: $0.0, image: $0.1) } }
```

That last `map` might not be strictly necessary if you are comfortable with working with a `Zip2Sequence`.

The above assumes that `Post` has an `imageURL: URL` property.

---

Let's clean that up a bit:

```
let postsWithImages = postsRepository
    .fetchPosts()
    .flatMap { posts in
        Observable.combineLatest(
            posts
                .map { $0.imageURL }
                .map { URLSession.shared.rx.image(for: $0) }
            )
            .map { zip(posts, $0) }
    }
    .map { $0.map { (post: $0.0, image: $0.1) } }
```

The above requires a new function:

```
extension Reactive where Base == URLSession {
    func image(for url: URL) -> Observable<UIImage?> {
        return data(request: URLRequest(url: url))
            .map { UIImage(data: $0) }
            .catchErrorJustReturn(nil)
    }
}
```

---

I figured I would add some explanation. As I mentioned in my article, [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f), the magic here is the use of `combineLatest` to convert an `[Observable<T>]` into an `Observable<[T]>`.

The operator takes the array of Observables, subscribes to all of them, waits for them all to complete, then emits an event with an array of all the values gathered. (After that it would emit a new array each time one of the items updated, but that isn't relevant here.)